# install SSH2 (server?) on FreeBSD

Tags: ssh, installation, freebsd

At work we have freeBSD testmachine. And we have a PHP script that uses SSH2 protocol to connect with the freeBSD server. With this script I'm not able to connect to the freeBSD server. 
I wanted to install it, but I'm not sure where to find the right source to compile.

The connection can be made with a different machine, but isntalling a new distro isn't the solution right now.

I can connect to the server over ssh, but not with the ssh2 protocol in PHP (http://nl.php.net/ssh2).

Comment: What version of FreeBSD?  What's the output of "uname -srm"?  How about the version of ssh: "ssh -v"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FreeBSD has OpenSSH-server installed by default

Enable it with sshd_enable=YES in rc.conf, and run "sh /etc/rc.d/sshd start"

Edit: Make sure "Protocol 2" is enabled in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and reload sshd with "sh /etc/rc.d/sshd reload".

Comment: I can connect to the server with SSH. That ain't the problem. But not by the SSH2 protocol. this is different from SSH1.

Comment: Please paste the output from "grep 'Protocol' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"

Comment: sshd_enable="YES" is allready set

Comment: FreeBSD's SSH server uses tcp_wrappers.  Make sure that /etc/hosts.allow allows ssh access from the server running the php/ssh script.

Comment: I repeat, please post the output from "grep 'Protocol' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"

Comment: is says: 
#Protocol 2

Comment: the php script is running from the same server as where I'm connecting from with my terminal. It seams that the Protocol 2 is not enabled like pauska is implying, I think. Am I right pauska?

Comment: No, it seems like it's running Protocol 2 by default (as new FreeBSD installs does). Try "ssh -2 -l username localhost" at the console of the server and see if it can connect.

Comment: I've replaced the #Protocol 2 with Protocol 2 and found somewhere else how to reload this config. Now I can connect with the server, but now I need to enable the authentication method "password" for this script.

Please provide the #Protocol 2 grep example and some explenation in your answer. 

The "ssh -2 -l myownusername" is not working. keeps saying "usage: bla bla"

Comment: Then you didnt type the command correctly. "ssh -2 -l username servername". Example: "ssh -2 -l pauska localhost".

Comment: that is working. The script is connecting now. So problem is fixed. But I needed to know something about the config and you let me know where to find it. Put in your answer something about the config and I can accept your answer

Comment: I've edited my original answer now.

Answer (score 2):

make sure sshd_enable="YES" is in /etc/rc.conf

/etc/rc.d/sshd keygen

/etc/rc.d/sshd start

SSHv2 is allowed by default, but freebsd also allows sshv1. I set protocol to 2 only, but this should be option for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Either build it by doing

```
cd /usr/ports/security/ssh2
make && make install
```

or install it using

```
pkg_add -r ssh2
```

This should do the trick.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: OpenSSH (the ssh server/client included in the base FreeBSD system) supports the SSH2 protocol (and only SSH2) by default since SSH1 has security issues.  The installation of the ssh2 port shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Open terminal and use bellow commands to install ssh2

**cd /usr/ports/security/ssh2
make && make install**

or use

**pkg install ssh2**

this should work properly

Comment: I don't think this adds anything that Halfdan's answer doesn't - and *that* has been criticised for being wrong.