# freebsd server access remotely

Tags: linux, freebsd, remote-access

I want to install freeBSD on a used dell server that I just bought. Can I put that box in a room and manage it remotely (no keyboard, monitor attached to it) from my linux laptop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [install SSH2  (server?) on FreeBSD](http://serverfault.com/questions/90192/install-ssh2-server-on-freebsd)

Answer (score 1):

SSH is the usual way. An alternative would be KVM/IP which can usually access the server before it has fully booted too.

Comment: So, KVM is a switch right? I need some sort of software only solution. Also, if I use SSH to connect to a machine, I have a few questions:                                                             1) I have att dsl at home, so everytime I reboot the machine, I will get a new IP, that means, I need to know the IP and then I Can connect, right? am I missing anything here?                                                                2) can I get GUI (like remote desktop) via ssh?                                                                 Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The OpenSSH daemon and client will likely be key cogs in this process.

Comment: Can I also have graphical interface with ssh?